# How do I define a binary operation on a set of numbers in prolog?

Tags: prolog

How do I define a binary operation on a list in prolog and then check its properties such as closure , associative, transitive , identity etc. ? I am new to prolog.. I don't know whether it is the place to ask but I tried and I didn't come across anything somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In Prolog you define *predicates*, i.e. relations among a symbol (called *functor*) and its arguments.

A predicate doesn't have a 'return value', just a 'truth value', depending of whether it can be evaluated WRT its arguments. Then your question it's not easy to answer.

Associativity, transitivity, identity, are of little help when it come down to speaking about predicates. The first and most common property we wish to evaluate is *termination*, because Prolog control flow it's a bit unusual and can easily lead to infinite recursion.

Anyway, the simpler *binary relation* on a list is member/2, that holds when its first argument it's an *element* of the second argument (the list).

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

I can't see any benefit in assessing that it's not associative, neither transitive (its arguments are of different types !).

Common operations like [intersection](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3), [union](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=union/3), etc typically needs 3 arguments, where the last is the result of the operation performed between 2 lists.

Identity in Prolog (that is an implementation of [first order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)) deserves a special role. Indeed, the usual programming symbol [=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=%29/2) used to assess identity, really performs a (potentially) complex operation, called *unification*. You can see from the (succint) documentation page that it's 'just' a matching between arbitrary terms.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
% Define sets I want to try
set7([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]).

% Define operations

% Sum modulo 7
sum7(X, Y, R) :-
    R is (X+Y) mod 7.

% Normal sum
nsum(X, Y, R) :-
    R is X + Y.

% A given set is closed if there is not a single case which
% indicates that it is not closed

closed(S, Operator) :-
    \+ n_closed(S, Operator, _), !.

% This predicate will succeed if it finds one pair of elements
% from S which, when operated upon, will give a result R which
% is outside of the set

n_closed(S, Operator, R) :-
    member(X, S),
    member(Y, S),
    Operation =.. [Operator, X, Y, R],
    Operation,
    \+ member(R, S).
```

When you execute it, you get these results:

```
| ?- set7(S), closed(S, sum7).

(1 ms) yes
| ?- set7(S), closed(S, nsum).

no
```

I'm not convinced my closure check is optimal, but it gives some ideas for how to play with it.